# How to increase qr code image size in laravel when i used simple-qrcode Package

Tags: laravel

```
$qrcode = \QrCode::size(5000)
            ->backgroundColor(255, 255, 0)->color(255, 0, 127)
            ->format('png')->merge('siteware/logo.png', 0.3, true)
            ->generate($qurcode, base_path($qurcode_png));
```

I used this code in controller and store qr code image in my folder but i cant get big qrcode images. its download only 33*33 size image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$qrcode = \QrCode::size(5000)
            ->backgroundColor(255, 255, 0)->color(255, 0, 127)
            ->format('png')->merge('siteware/logo.png', 0.3, true)
            ->generate($qurcode, base_path($qurcode_png));
```

in above code order is matter

correct code:

```
$qrcode = \QrCode::backgroundColor(255, 255, 0)->color(255, 0, 127)
            ->format('png')->merge('siteware/logo.png', 0.3, true)->size(1000)
            ->generate($qurcode, base_path($qurcode_png));
```